# Cenverting any date to Full Date format(Tuesday 27th july 2016) from any date format

Tags: javascript

i want  to convert date to full date format like Tuesday 27th july 2016 from any date format in javascript ,how can i do that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype)

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you are pretty free to parse whatever format if you provide it to moment.

```
var format1 = "DD.MM.YYYY"
var format2 = "DDfoobarbazMMfoobarbazYYYY";
var date1 = "24.02.1995"
var date2 = "24foobarbaz02foobarbaz1995";

console.log(moment(date1, format1).format("LLLL"));
console.log(moment(date2, format2).format("LLLL"));
```

The examples will output

```
Friday, February 24, 1995 12:00 AM
```

for both dates, even though date2 is very ugly

Comment: yes,but i want date in this(Tuesday 27th july 2016) format,can we i get it through moment.js?